# Python Syntax Error not showing?

Tags: python

```
import sys
import time
print ("Hello Eric the builder")
print ("This program will calculate how many bricks are required to build an igloo")
# Start, print brick types
start = input("Enter YES to start: ")
if start.lower() == "yes" :
    print ("(1) Budget - length: 45cm x height: 25cm x depth: 15cm")
    print ("(2) Superior - length: 35cm x height: 25cm x depth: 20cm")
    print ("(3) Luxury - length: 30cm x height: 20cm x depth: 25cm")

selection = input("Select your brick type")


# When selection has been made
if input == "budget".lower() or "1":
    print ("\nYou have selected (1) Budget ")
    print ("Please note tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)")
    tunnel1 = int(input("Enter in the length of the igloo's tunnel in cm"))
    dome1 = int(input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm"))
    print ("\n This program will now calculate the number of bricks required")
tunnelarea = pi*tunnel1*45 + pi*45**2 #mathematical calculations
domearea = 2*pi*dome1**2 - 0.5*(45+15)**2
bricksrequired = tunnelarea + domearea /(45*25)
print ("\n The number of brick required is"),bricksrequired


elif input == "superior".lower() or "2":
print ("\nYou have selected (2) Superior")
print ("Please note tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)")
tunnel1 =  int(input("Enter in the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm"))
dome2 = int(input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm"))
tunnelarea = pi*tunnel2*45 + pi*45**2
domearea = 2*pi*dome2*2 - 0.5*(45+20)**2 
bricksrequired = tunnelarea + domearea /(35*25)
print ("\n The number of brick required is"),bricksrequired


elif input == "luxury".lower() or "3":
print ("\nYou have selected (3) Luxury")
```

I'm getting a syntax error when I try to run this program but it doesn't show where. Also, how can I get this program to restart after it finishes or when a value is restricted? Thanks in advance, much appreciated

```
print ("Please note tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)")
tunnel3 = int(input("Enter in the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm"))
dome3 = int(input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm"))
tunnelarea = pi*tunnel3*45 + pi*45**2
domearea = 2*pi*dome3*2 - 0.5*(45+25)**2
bricksrequired = tunnelarea + domearea /(30*20)
print ("\n The number of brick required is"),bricksrequired

if dome_radius < 45 :
    print ("\nInvalid input. Please enter a value larger than 45!")
```

Comment: Can you include the full text of the error you get when you try to run the program?

Comment: It just says "syntax error". Btw at the beginning it's supposed to be 'import math' instead of 'import time'

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: @AndrewMagee I'm just pressing f5?

Comment: you syntax is invalid at `elif input == "superior".lower() or "2":`

Comment: In what program? If you're using a program that just says "syntax error" and *really* doesn't tell you where, try running the `.py` file from the command line and then you'll get an actually useful error message.

Comment: Yes, as letsc said, you have `elif` statements under an `if` statement, but they aren't indented, so the Python interpreter thinks you just have an `elif` hanging out in space.

Comment: @letsc How do I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mr Licharde heff fun.

```
# When selection has been made
if str(input).lower() == "budget" or "1":
    print ("\nYou have selected (1) Budget ")
    print ("Please note tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)")
    tunnel1 = int(input("Enter in the length of the igloo's tunnel in cm"))
    dome1 = int(input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm"))
    print ("\n This program will now calculate the number of bricks required")
    #mathematical calculations
    tunnelarea = pi*tunnel1*45 + pi*45**2
    domearea = 2*pi*dome1**2 - 0.5*(45+15)**2
    bricksrequired = tunnelarea + domearea /(45*25)
    print ("\n The number of brick required is"),bricksrequired

elif str(input).lower() == "superior" or "2":
    print ("\nYou have selected (2) Superior")
    print ("Please note tunnel radius is 45cm(fixed)")
    tunnel1 =  int(input("Enter in the length of your igloo's tunnel in cm"))
    dome2 = int(input("Enter in the radius of your dome in cm"))
    tunnelarea = pi*tunnel2*45 + pi*45**2
    domearea = 2*pi*dome2*2 - 0.5*(45+20)**2 
    bricksrequired = tunnelarea + domearea /(35*25)
    print ("\n The number of brick required is"),bricksrequired
```

Solutions to the issues of the original code:

- Use str() on input to change it to string, in order to use .lower()

`if input` to `if str(input).lower()`

- Remove .lower() from "budget" and "superior". Just really weird code.

`"budget".lower()` to `"budget"`

- Indents. Removing an indent means that the `if` is no longer in use. An `elif` needs to be tied to, or in other words, be right under an `if`. Thus, the original code did not work and came back with a syntax error.

Comment: Could you add something explaining how/why this solves the original question

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple issues. first off, use `.lower()` with your input statements and not on strings. You want to change the USER INPUT into lowercase and not you strings.

you have:

```
selection = input("Select your brick type")
elif input == "superior".lower() or "2":
```

what you should have :

```
selection = input("Select your brick type").lower()
elif input == "superior" or selection == "2":
```

Answer (score 0):

You have repeated the same error in multiple places, so lets start with the first instance:

```
selection = input("Select your brick type")


# When selection has been made
if input == "budget".lower() or "1":
```

`input` is the name of a function, you are comparing a function with a string. You need to compare what the user enters as a result of that function, which is stored in `selection`:

```
if selection.lower() == '1':
```

You have the same problem here: `elif input == "superior".lower() or "2":`, this line should be `elif selection.lower() == '2':`